# Retrieve an ArrayListMultimap Key

Tags: java, collections, guava

I'm using Guava's  [`ArrayListMultimap<K,V>`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) collection to map `Integers` to `Strings`. The class provides a method called [`containsValue(Object value)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#containsValue(java.lang.Object)) which checks if the Multimap contains the specified value for any key. Once I determine that is true, what's the best way to retrieve said key?

```
ArrayListMultimap<String, Integer> myMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

if (myMap.containsValue(new Integer(1))
{
   // retrieve the key? 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `containsValue` you could iterate over [myMap.entries()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#entries()) which returns a collection of all key-value pairs. The iterator generated by the returned collection traverses the values for one key, followed by the values of a second key, and so on:

```
Integer toFind = new Integer(1);
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: myMap.entries()) {
    if (toFind.equals(entry.getValue())) {
        // entry.getKey() is the first match
    }
}
// handle not found case
```

If you look at the implementation of [`containsValue`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#containsValue(java.lang.Object)) it just iterates over the map's values so the performance of doing this with `map.entries()` instead of `map.values()` should be about the same.

```
public boolean containsValue(@Nullable Object value) {
    for (Collection<V> collection : map.values()) {
      if (collection.contains(value)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
}
```

In the general case of course there isn't necessarily a unique key for a given value so unless you know that in your map each value only occurs against a single key you would need to specify the behaviour e.g. if you wanted the first key or last key.